# Why does toggling a checkbox/radiobutton with JavaScript fail after calling event.preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, checkbox, jquery-events

Consider this sample code:

```
<span>
    <input type="checkbox">
</span>
```

```
$('span').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(':checkbox')[0].checked = true;
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/R2Awe/)

From my knowledge, this should happen:

- `preventDefault()` should prevent the checkbox from being checked by the browser's default behavior, even if the event handler is attached above in the DOM hierarchy. This part works correctly.
- Setting `.checked = true` should work as, I believe, it should be independent of the browser's default action for the event which I've cancelled. This part seems buggy, as if the `preventDefault()` was affecting it -- remove the `preventDefault()` and it works as intended.

**What's the actual reason why the checkbox stays always unchecked?**

I've tested on Chrome 33 and Firefox 27, so this doesn't seem to be a browser bug.

This question is mostly due to curiosity to extend my DOM/Event model knowledge. I don't want workarounds, but rather I want to know why this example fails.

Comment: See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R2Awe/10/) when you click on text `e.preventDefault()` doesn't interface with default behaviour

Comment: @Satpal the click event is bound to span not to the child, so what is actually going on.

Comment: I'm really confused on what happen, good question!

Comment: @Satpal thanks, it seems to further prove what kamilkp answered previously, the checkbox seems to get unchecked after the `click` event due to the mouse event, not sure though as (AFAIK) there is no event that follows a click event.

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435142/is-this-a-core-misunderstanding-of-the-default-click-event-on-checkbox-inputs-o

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I know about event bubbling, my expected behavior describes bubbling. Unless you meant something else.

Comment: @Musa thanks, that looks useful. I'll read it throughout.

Comment: @Musa `preventDefault` rollbacks the checked state to its original state, that seems to be the most plausible answer. I'll check the specs to see if anything backs that up.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: I added spec references to my answer now too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your HTML:

```
<span>
    <input type="checkbox">
</span>
```

and your code:

```
$('span').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(':checkbox')[0].checked = true;
});
```

Event bubbling is your issue here.

When clicking the `checkbox`, the click event is propagated to the `span`. `e.preventDefault()` is the called on the event object propagated from the `checkbox`.

Hence `preventDefault()` is execute against the `checkbox` itself, preventing it from being checked.

Ones the click event of the `checkbox` is "cancelled" by means of `preventDefault` it will stay cancelled until completion of the event flow. (See bottom of answer for more details on that)

If you apply some styling to the span you notice that clicking around the `checkbox` your code works as expected but clicking on the `checkbox` itself replicates your issue due to the above mentioned.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/V6mUr/) - Original Fiddle + styles. Clicking `span` is fine, `checkbox` is not

---

According to the [**MDN documentation on preventDefault()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault):

> Calling `preventDefault` during any stage of event flow cancels the
>   event, meaning that any default action normally taken by the
>   implementation as a result of the event will not occur.

The [**DOM Level 2 Spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-preventDefault) also notes:

> If an event is cancelable, the `preventDefault` method is used to
>   signify that the event is to be canceled, meaning any default action
>   normally taken by the implementation as a result of the event will not
>   occur. **If, during any stage of event flow, the preventDefault method
>   is called the event is canceled**.

The [**DOM Level 3 Events Spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow-default-cancel) notes under Example 5:

> The default action associated with the `click` event on `<input type="checkbox">` elements toggles the `checked` IDL attribute value of that element. If the `click` event's default action is cancelled, then the value is restored to its former state.

Comment: That way the `click` event handler on `span` is never called.

Comment: "Hence preventDefault() is execute against the checkbox itself, preventing it from being checked." - yes, that was my expected behavior. The problem is not applying the preventDefault against the input, the problem is why the line of code which sets the checked state does not work as intended after `preventDefault()`.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: `the line of code which sets the checked state does not work` it doesn't work because the first event captured by the span was the bubbled up click event from the checkbox and it was told to no do it's default behaviour. By the time your line of code executes the event chain is still active and the instructions to prevent the default behaviour are too.

Comment: Guess we aren't communicating very well. Let's try another way, I understand that a click on the checkbox bubbles up to the span which in turns `preventDefault` the click on the checkbox. Question is, why the `.checked = true` fails?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: look at the answer of the SO post linked in the commets of your question. `The misunderstanding probably occurs because you are thinking of the event as firing after the actual click has been fully processed (i.e. the checkbox has been toggled) while in reality the event model stipulates that the handler fires while the event is being processed.` That is what I'm trying to tell you with `By the time your line of code executes the event chain is still active and the instructions to prevent the default behaviour are too` The other person explains it better though :)

Comment: Oh makes sense. If you can link/quote the spec which describes the rollback to original state I'll accept the answer. `=]` And yes, this is mostly a theoretical question -- in my actual code the checkboxes are hidden so they won't receive click events.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: I re-wrote my answer and removed any chat about work-arounds as you said yourself you just wanted to know why this happens. I re-wrote the explanation and hopefully I explained it better now than in my comments :) I also added the links to the MDN and the W3 DOM level 2 documentation which note those behaviours too. That's all I could find in regards to the spec documentation, hope this helps.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl thanks for all the effort! Mind quoting [DOM level 3 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow-default-cancel) with the Example 5 as well?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Added that too. Nice find :) Thanks for asking the question as well as, even though I knew why it happened I never thought about how I might explain this or where in the spec it states that. +1ed the question off course :)

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping part of the code in a `setTimeout` does the trick, as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/y7C77/

```
$('span').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('input').prop('checked', true);
    }, 1);
});
```

`preventDefault()` cancels the default action, and I think that it's able to cancel it even if you manually do what the browser would do (in this case: altering the `checked` property).

Comment: `setTimeout` works because the inner function executes after the event flow has been fully completed which called `preventDefault` on the propagated `checkbox` event object. Nice work around :)

Comment: I was thinking about the same around, but well, this is a theoretical question. +1 though for the nice workaround in case anyone in the future needs it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior what I feel since, when you say event.preventDefault() you are instructing the browser not to do any operation on it in this event. So, even after the statement when you explicitly check the checkbox, browser will not do any operation on it.
We can see the difference when I change the event as follows:

```
$('span').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     //$(':checkbox')[0].checked = true;
     setTimeout(function(){$(':checkbox')[0].checked = true;});
});
```

Using timeout we are changing the checked property outside the event, hence its get checked.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to `preventDefault` both `click` and `mouseup` and set the checked on `mouseup`

try:

```
$('span').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).mouseup(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(':checkbox')[0].checked = true;
});
```

Comment: there are several other better workarounds though.....the question is **What's the actual reason why the checkbox stays always unchecked?** and you have not answered it.

Comment: You are calling `preventDefault` on span. When you click on input, the click event bubbles up the DOM. And in `span's` event listener it has already happened on `input`. The checkbox gets checked and then unchecked shortly after that so you don't even see it.

Comment: @kamilkp Why is it unchecked?

Comment: @kamilkp yes that makes sense, though there's still something feeling wrong. `mouseup` happens before `click`, and `preventDefault`ing `mouseup` does not fix the behavior with `click`: http://jsfiddle.net/V3pW6/1/